Ansible error "No module named 'ansible.module_utils.six.moves'"
I used a Fedora 39 machine to manage a Fedora 39 machine, with an Ansible playbook.  This worked OK.
I tried to use Ubuntu 22.04 to run the same playbook, targeting the same Fedora 39 machine.   It failed.  Why did it fail?
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [alan-laptop]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"ansible.legacy.setup": {"failed": true, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to alan-laptop closed.
", "module_stdout": "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/home/alan-sysop/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1716281784.2385828-132440-85599417152925/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 102, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File \"/home/alan-sysop/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1716281784.2385828-132440-85599417152925/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File \"/home/alan-sysop/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1716281784.2385828-132440-85599417152925/AnsiballZ_setup.py\", line 37, in invoke_module
    from ansible.module_utils import basic
  File \"/tmp/ansible_ansible.legacy.setup_payload_0vjz3har/ansible_ansible.legacy.setup_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 176, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible.module_utils.six.moves'
", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup"}

My Ansible package is version 2.10.7+merged+base+2.10.8+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1~esm1.

Fedora 39 uses Python 3.12.  This is said to be too new (?) for this version of Ansible.
In any case, I do not expect the version of Ansible included in Ubuntu 22.04 to be fixed.
The error can be avoided by using a newer version of Ansible, for example ansible-core 2.16.6-1ppa~jammy from the Ansible PPA for Ubuntu.  See also the NOTE below.
Credit: tkn on the Ubuntu MATE community
ansible-core 2.16 supports python versions 3.6-3.12 on the target node, according to the ansible-core support matrix.
It also supports python2 version 2.7.  So, it might also be possible to use python2. (Install python2, and set ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/python2").
NOTE: I was using a version of Ansible from Ubuntu ESM repos.  If you have Ubuntu ESM repos enabled, the standard instructions to install Ansible from the Ansible PPA for Ubuntu will not do anything.  After enabling the PPA, I used Package > "Force version" in the synaptic graphical package manager.  Alternatively, you could find the newer version number and install that specifically, using apt-cache search ansible and apt install ansible=$VERSION.  I don't know whether this will let future Ansible updates install automatically.
